Gaussian linear model marginal likelihood under g-prior
Consider a Gaussian linear model with an $ n \times 1 $ outcome vector $ y $ and an $ n \times p $ matrix of centered predictors $ X $:
$ y = \iota\alpha + X\beta + \varepsilon \quad \quad \varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I) $
with priors $ p(\alpha, \sigma^2) = \sigma^{-2} $ and g-prior $ p(\beta \mid \sigma^2) = \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^2 g (X'X)^{-1}\right) $. It appears to be a well-known fact that the marginal likelihood $p(y)$ can be derived in the very convenient form
$ p(y) = \frac{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}^{(n-1)}\sqrt{n}} \|{y} - \bar{{y}}\|^{-(n-1)} \times (1 + g)^{(n-1-p)/2} \times [1 + g(1 - R^2)]^{-(n-1)/2} $
where $ R^2 $ is the coefficient of determination when regressing $ y $ on $ X $ and an intercept. This is stated in various sources, for example here (Eq. 5) and here (Eq. 10).
Is there any textbook or "original paper" that provides the derivation of this specific result in detail? I am aware of Bayesian conjugate regression updates in general, but no source I know of covers this specific setting (including solving the integral over $ \sigma^2 $ under improper prior after integrating out $ \beta $ and $ \alpha $).

It is derived in our book, The Bayesian Core.
